# How to detect whether a browser supports window.close?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm building an app, where the auth flow goes as follows

- user clicks login button
- a login window opens.
- The user is redirected to either Facebook, Google or Twitter, depending on the querystring of the window.
- When the user comes back from fb/google/twitter, my backend generates an auth token, and the popup window uses postMessage to send the auth token to the main page, verifying the origin
- the main page closes th window after receiving the token.

This flow works great on desktop devices, but not in mobile browsers, where window.open opens a new tab that can't be programmatically closed.

On mobile devices, I can redirect the user to the login screen, and send them back with the auth token in the hash fragment (oauth2 implicit flow), but I only want to do that when I have to. How do I detect whether window.close works without browser sniffing?

## What I've tried

I've tried using a HTML/JS based modal dialog with an iframe in it, but Google's login page doesn't allow embedding it in an iFrame, I haven't tried with other providers

Comment: Use jquery or other js framework dialog not windows or popup.

Comment: the thing is that during the login process, I redirect to Google, Facebook or Twitter. Google's login page doesn't want to be embedded inside an iframe. I've tried that already, but thanks for your answer anyway, @Jkike.

Comment: @Jkike Sometimes a popup is the correct solution. It sounds like it might be in this case.

Comment: `var supportsclose = ("close" in window) && typeof window["close"] === "function";`

Comment: @j08691 That only works if window.close is undefined in the browsers though, right?

Comment: But if he must use it in a mobile enviroment it will always result in a problem. :( Doesn't google have an api for login ?

Comment: For what it's worth, popups work fine on all various versions of my Android devices.

Comment: @Jkike yes, they do exactly for that reason ;) You should google that and provide as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `window.close()` is supported by object detection:

```
if (window.close) {
    alert ('window close is supported');
}
```

Do the check without paranthesis `()`, as you don't want to execute the function, but want to check for existance of the function/object.

Comment: desktop chrome says window.close() is a function, but that doesn't tell us if calling it works or not...